# How to keep .net framework without sleep after a certain time

Tags: .net, frameworks

I have an issue regarding the .net framework. .net framework always sleep after a certain timeout.

Because of that, if the first user to access the .net application which uses.Net framework, its response of the application became to slow too much.   I am thinking that it was caused by loading the .net framework from the first access. After the first user access the application, the second access response time become so quickly. Only first access time always too much slow.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The question's a bit vague, but I'm going to guess that by ".NET" you mean you have an ASP.NET web application and it wakes up when the first user accesses it.

This is configurable within IIS Manager.
The settings differ a bit based on the version of Windows that you have.

Application Pool:
    Start Mode: Always Running
    Idle Timeout (minutes): 0
Application:
    Preload Enabled: true

Comment: Thank you first for your reply.
When the first user comes in, it wakes up and then goes back to standby after 15 minutes of inactivity.
The OS is Windows Sever 2008 R2. There is no Start Mode  when I go into the Application Pool from the IIS Manager menu. Where can I find the startup mode?